# How to get customized cell and use it's customized item by indexpath - swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a question to get my customized cell.
I use my customized cell item will get error.
What's wrong with me?

```
let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.contents.count-1, section: 0)

   var cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: insertIndexPath)

        if cell is MyTextTableViewCell {

        cell = MyTextTableViewCell() as MyTextTableViewCell
        cell.checkImageView.isHidden = true //error here
        cell.warningButton.isHidden = true //error here

      }else if cell is MyImageTableViewCell {

          cell = MyImageTableViewCell() as MyImageTableViewCell
          cell.checkImageView.isHidden = true //error here
          cell.warningButton.isHidden = true //error here
      }
```

error like this:

> Value of type 'UITableViewCell?' has no member 'checkImageView'

Comment: where are you trying to "customize" your cells?

Comment: i use xib to customize my cells.

Comment: have you registered your customize cell?

Answer (score 0):

You are using custom cell class to ensure whether cell instance belongs to that particular class or not.

Actually you need to create an instance of custom cell class using `if-let` block.

Try this and see:

```
let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.contents.count-1, section: 0)

if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: insertIndexPath) as? MyTextTableViewCell {
    cell.checkImageView.isHidden = true 
    cell.warningButton.isHidden = true 

} else if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: insertIndexPath) as? MyImageTableViewCell {

    cell.checkImageView.isHidden = true 
    cell.warningButton.isHidden = true 
} else if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: insertIndexPath) {

    print("cell description -- \(cell.description)")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do like this :

```
let index = IndexPath(row: self.contents.count-1, section: 0)

if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as? MyTextTableViewCell {
    cell.checkImageView.isHidden = true
    cell.warningButton.isHidden = true

} else if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: insertIndexPath) as? MyImageTableViewCell {

cell.checkImageView.isHidden = true
cell.warningButton.isHidden = true
} else if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: insertIndexPath) {

print("cell is not from required one -- \(cell.description)")
}
```